# rails polymorphic associations, redirection depending on model, using the model's controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, polymorphic-associations

in the application i'm working on, i need to install a notification system.

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true
end

class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :notifications, as: :notifiable
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :notifications, as: :notifiable
end
```

after created, the notifications should redirect to differents view depending on the notification type, so it could be forthe same model and different redirections ( so the redirect_to notification.notifiable isn't a solution since i need many different redirections for that same model, not only the show).
working with polymorphic_path or url, also dont give different redirections, only defined prefix helpers.

what i need more explicitly, for example there let's take two different types of notifications, the one where a request is submited, so clicking on it will redirect to the request itself, but when the request is done the user will be redirected to his dashboard.

i dont want to redirect to the notifications_controller and test on the model and then test again on the notification type, i hope that the polymorphism here could help. is there a way to call a method in the controller model (the model is detected from the polymorphic association )

and thanks

Comment: "is there a way to call a method in the controller model." What about: @notification.notifiable.is_a?(Request)

Comment: I'm having trouble with your terminology. Clicking on something doesn't "redirect to the request", but I think you might be too tied to not doing things in the notifications_controller regardless. Can you describe more concrete steps for what you would like to see happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up adding an attribute to the notification model, message_type : integer.
Once the notification is clicked on, the redirection will always be the same : to a methode in the NotificationController (redirect_notification), now the notification known, also the depending model is too (from the polymorphic relation).
in the NotificationController :

```
def redirect_notification    
   notification =Notification.find(params[:id]) // here i get the notification  
   notification.notifiable.get_notification_path(notification.message_type)
end
```

we take advantage of the poymorphic when using notification.notifiable.
So, i define a method called get_notification_path(message_type) in each model who have a polymorphic association with notifications, as example :

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notifications, as: :notifiable
  def get_notification_path(message_type)
    if message_type == 0
       "/documents"// this is just an example, here you can put any redirection you want, you can include url_helpers.
    elsif message_type == 1
       url_for user_path
    end
  end
end
```

This way, i get the redirection i need, using the polymorphic associations and without adding unneeded routes.

Comment: in this project, adding the both notifications and history that are shown in a context( each context depend on where the user is), so he will view specific notif and histories. if anyone need details about the making of it feel free to ask.